# POST request to flask server for automated testing. 400 Bad Request, KeyError 'files'

Tags: python, post, flask, request, keyerror

I am trying to create an endpoint called /automated_testing. This endpoint will
receive an automated POST request which will be a .txt file which contains some strings. I want to read those strings and perform some operations on it.

I am getting error :

> raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
>   werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   KeyError: 'files'

I am using the below code to send a request which I trigger from separate script.

```
import requests

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/automated_testing', files={'test.txt': f})
```

Code for the flask server

```
@app.route('/automated_testing', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getfile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['files']
        a = ""
        with open(file,'r') as f:
            file_content = f.read()
            a+=file_content
        return a    
    else:
        return "GET REQ"

    return "Hi"
```

Content of test.txt

```
Hi
hello
```

I get that the error indicates ['files'] but I am not able to resolve the problem. Is the way I am sending the post request wrong or the flask server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 file = request.files['text.txt']
```

or iterate over all sent files:

```
    for file in request.files:
        #do_stuff
```

Comment: This does return a FileStorage object! But is there any other way. Thing is I won't be knowing the name of the file will be sent for testing?

Comment: you can iterate over all key value pairs in request.files, I will edit my post above with an example